# Not Getting expiry date in DataEntryActivity class of 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'

Tags: android, android-studio, payment

I am getting the problem of not getting expiry date and card holder name in  DataEntryActivity class of`'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'` but while enter the expiry date and cardholder name in editText of DataEntryActivity then getting properly , but not able to get expiry and cardholder name while scanning the card.

I am using this code [link is here](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/blob/master/SampleApp/src/main/java/io/card/development/SampleActivity.java)

using this dependencies  compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'

my code is here,

```
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), CardIOActivity.class);

        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, true); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_EXPIRY, true);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CARDHOLDER_NAME, true); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, true); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_CAPTURED_CARD_IMAGE, true);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON, false);


        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_GUIDE_COLOR, getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
        // matches the theme of your application
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME, false); // default: false

        // MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE is arbitrary and is only used within this activity.
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_CAPTURED_CARD_IMAGE, false);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_RETURN_CARD_IMAGE, false);
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, true);
        startActivityForResult(scanIntent, MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and for the activity result. this code is working proper in my activity

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        String resultStr;
        if (data != null && data.hasExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT)) {
            CreditCard scanResult = data.getParcelableExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_RESULT);

            // Never log a raw card number. Avoid displaying it, but if necessary use getFormattedCardNumber()
            String resultStr1 = scanResult.getFormattedCardNumber();
            resultStr = "Card Number: " + scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber() + "\n";

            if (scanResult.getRedactedCardNumber() != null) {
                cardNoFlag = true;

                edtMaskedCardNo.setText(scanResult.getFormattedCardNumber());
            }
            scanResult.getCardType();

            // Do something with the raw number, e.g.:
            // myService.setCardNumber( scanResult.cardNumber );
            String expYr = "", month = "";
            if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {

                expYr = String.valueOf(scanResult.expiryYear % 100);
                if (isSingle(scanResult.expiryMonth)) {
//                    month = String.format("%02d", scanResult.expiryMonth);
                    month = String.valueOf("0" + scanResult.expiryMonth);
                } else {
                    month = String.valueOf(scanResult.expiryMonth);
                }
                resultStr += "Expiration Date: " + scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + scanResult.expiryYear + "\n";
                ExpDateFlag = true;

                b.putBoolean("ExpDateFlag", ExpDateFlag);
                strExpDate = month + "/" + expYr;
                b.putString("ExpDate", month + "/" + expYr);

                b.putString("FormattedExpDate", month.concat(expYr));
                strFormattedExpiry = month.concat(expYr);

                /*Amit Verma set Expire*/
                edtExpDate.setText(month + "/" + expYr);
            }


            if (scanResult.cardholderName != null) {
                resultStr += "Cardholder Name : " + scanResult.cardholderName + "\n";
            }

            if (scanResult.cvv != null) {
// //                 Never log or display a CVV
                strScanCVV = scanResult.cvv;
            }



        } else {

            resultStr = "Scan was canceled.";

        }


    }
```

but not able to get the expiry date and card holder name here [image: see image description here]

Comment: In some credit card you need enter manually

Comment: Jaldeep but same card scanning in iOS is working fine and getting expiry date

Comment: Please check this code ......if (scanResult.isExpiryValid()) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty("" + scanResult.expiryMonth) && !TextUtils.isEmpty("" + scanResult.expiryYear)) {
                    edtExpiryDate.setText(scanResult.expiryMonth + "/" + String.valueOf(scanResult.expiryYear).substring(2, 4));
                }
            }

Comment: @FalduJaldeep I am getting proper details in my onActivity Result but not able to get in library DataEntryActivity , I have added  image as well of this , please check that